# Using a function in a for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I wrote a function to write a file based on different inputs. The function works fine when I used it for individual part. However, when I used a for loop to do it, it does not work, I do not know why.

Below is my code

```
import controDictRead as CD
import numpy as np

Totallength=180000
x=np.arange(0.,Totallength,1.)  
h=300*np.ones(len(x))

Relaxationzone=1000 # Relaxation zone width

#I=2
#x_input=1000
#y_start=-200
y_end=9
z=0.05
nPoints=4000
dx=20000
threshold=1000
x_input=np.zeros(int(np.floor(Totallength/dx)))
y_start=np.zeros(len(x_input))
I=np.zeros(len(x_input))
for i in range(len(x_input)):
    if i==0:
        x_input[i]=Relaxationzone
    else:
        x_input[i]=dx*i
        if x_input[i]>=Totallength-Relaxationzone:
            x_input[i]=Totallength-Relaxationzone
    I[i]=i+1
    y_start[i]=np.interp(x_input[i],x,h)
    controlDict_new=CD.controlDicWritter(I,x_input[i],y_start[i],y_end,z,nPoints)
```

All I tried to do is to write a file called controlDict, It has a list of locations that has a format like the one below

```
location1
      {
        type uniform;
        axis y;
        start (1000 -300 0.05 );
        end   (1000 9 0.05 );
        nPoints 3000;
      }
```

All my controlDictRead function does is to find the location name (e.g. location1) I am interested in, and then replace the values (e.g. start, end, nPoints) to the one I inputted. This function works fine when I input these values one by one, for example

```
controlDict_new=CD.controlDicWritter(3,x_input[2],y_start[2],y_end,z,nPoints)
```

However, when I did it using a loop like the one shown at the beginning, it does not work, the loop stuck at the first location and kept writing values onto the first location throughout the loop, I am not sure why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the code for CD.controlDicWritter? We cannot reproduce this without it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to also see the source of the `controDictRead` module, but I have a suspicion what might be wrong:

Your code seems to be passing an entire array to `controlDictWriter`, but your example code appears to be passing a single integer. Is that intentional?